# UITableView / UINavigationBar Passes .tag from Child to Parent?

Tags: iphone, tags, parent, navbar

I am setting a tag for my navigationBar using:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tag = 1;
```

When you select a cell and the child UITableView loads, I set:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tag = 2;
```

But when I hit the 'back' button and the Parent UITableView appears again, the .tag is still set to 2.

I have tried setting tag=1 in the Parent's viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and in the Child's viewWillDisappear - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, only use .tag properties on non-system UIView classes.
You might be better off mapping these navbars in an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how to 'map these navbars in an NSMutableArray' ? The only way I've found to get my image into the navBar is to add:

 @implementation UINavigationBar(MyCustomBackground)
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
 {
      [[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-navigation-background.png"] drawInRect:self.bounds];
 }
 @end

to the .m file